# Sap Code Inspector - Generating a table of all PCodes linked to the classes

Tags: abap, sap-basis

I have problems to read the error codes and corresponding messages of SCI message classes.

Is there an way to easy access those?

I'm using "Praxishandbuch SAP Code Inspector" as a reference, but in that regard it is of no help.

I looked in `Se11` but the information to the messages isn't helpful.

Has someone an approch to build such a table?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Do you want to format the messages for output, filter out individual messages, ...?

Comment: I need a ruleset for my SonarPlugin.
At best rulenumber with corrosponding class and violation/information.  

This information i want to collect with an rfc and jco to create a xml rule file

Comment: I'm not sure I can help you there. Just out of curiosity - what is the benefit of doing such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, perhaps it will work for you. I use the code below to get the access to all the errors found by Code Inspector for particular user(s):

```
data: ref_inspec_a type ref to cl_ci_inspection.
ref_inspec_a = cl_ci_inspection=>get_ref(
    p_user          = pa_iuser
    p_name          = pa_inam
    p_vers          = pa_ivers ).

data: ls_resp type scir_resp,
      lt_resp type scit_resp.
clear: ls_resp, lt_resp.
ls_resp-sign = 'I'.
ls_resp-option = 'EQ'.
ls_resp-low = pa_fuser.
insert ls_resp into table lt_resp.

call method ref_inspec_a->get_results
  exporting
    p_responsibl          = lt_resp
  exceptions
    insp_not_yet_executed = 1
    overflow              = 2
    others                = 3.
```

Playing around with `LT_RESP` you can get results for more users at the same time.

After you execute the code above, you can check the attributes `SCIRESTPS` and `SCIRESTHD` of the object `REF_INSPEC_A`. These are the large tables, which contain the result data of the SCI check. You can either work with them on your own, or you can simply pass the object `REF_INSPEC_A` into the function module `SCI_SHOW_RESULTS` to get regular SCI user interface.

Comment: The problem is that i need a general discription of the rules first.
Collecting all occurrences of an inspection would be the second step

Comment: If you call `CL_CI_TESTS=>GET_TESTS`, you get the table of references to `IF_CI_TEST` and these references have attributes `DESCRIPTION` and `NAME` (you can find the value of `NAME` also in table `SCIRESTPS`, field `TEST`). If you need more details, there is even method `DISPLAY_DESCRIPTION`, and within the implementations of the method you can find pointers to SAP KW (usually). Is this what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that you can get all the changeable messages (found in SCI GoTo/Management Of/ Message Priorities) can be read from the scimessages attribute of the test classes.

With this help you can get about 60% of all errors.